# How to unblur text in a blurred div

Tags: html, css, blur

You can say that this is a duplication, but the other question + answers didn't work for me.

so. I am trying to blur the background where I want my text.
So I setted a background image using css. And created a div that has a opacity of `0.1` and is blurred. Now I want to fill in contents in that dev (text). But that text is also blurred! How can I fix this?

I have searched a lot online on how to blur, and unblur etc. Nothing actually works for me.

```html
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<style>
@font-face {
    font-family: ProximaNova;
    src: url("ProximaNova-Regular.otf") format("opentype");
}

@font-face {
    font-family: ProximaNova;
    font-weight: bold;
    src: url("ProximaNova-Bold.otf") format("opentype");
}
body {
  background-image: url("bg.png");
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
.aaa {
    position:fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width:30em;
    height:18em;
    margin-top: -9em; /*set to a negative number 1/2 of your height*/
    margin-left: -15em; /*set to a negative number 1/2 of your width*/
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background-color: #f3f3f3;
    opacity: 0.1;
    -webkit-filter: blur(4px);
    -moz-filter: blur(4px);
    -ms-filter: blur(4px);
    -o-filter: blur(4px);
    filter: blur(4px);
}
.b {
    background-image: url(bg.png);
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="aaa"><p>Hey, I want this text to NOT be blurred...</p></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is a codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YbWLgj

There is actually text in there, you can see it when you hover over with your mouse. Thanks for helping me!

Comment: I think blurring is transitive and affects all child nodes, including tetx. What you can do is to not set the blur on the text container, but on a separate child element with a sibling relation to the text. Perhaps you can even use the before pseudo element to not have to have extra noise in the html DOM.

Comment: Could you give me a example? @Eneroth3

Comment: `
/*
  Using ::before to blur psuedo element with siblign relation to text,
  rather than parent of text.
*/
.blurred-bg::before {
  /* Place below text so text can eb selected. */
  z-index: -1;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  /* Changed the background to make it visible against background. */
  background-color: #666;
  opacity: 0.1;
  -webkit-filter: blur(4px);
  -moz-filter: blur(4px);
  -ms-filter: blur(4px);
  -o-filter: blur(4px);
  filter: blur(4px);
}
`

Comment: /* Took the liberty to give class a meaningful name. */
.blurred-bg {
  position:fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width:30em;
  height:18em;
  margin-top: -9em; /*set to a negative number 1/2 of your height*/
  margin-left: -15em; /*set to a negative number 1/2 of your width*/
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

Comment: For whatever reason code formatting doesn't seem to work in the comments, the code exceed the allowed length of a single comment and I can't post an answer, but if you run the above two comments through some kind of css clean up utility I hope you can find it useful.